# sincronizar banco de dados Local com Web

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, cakephp, sincronização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em CakePHP, com banco MySQL. uma parte já está funcionando mas desde o começo preciso de uma solução para o seguinte problema:

Minha aplicação deve funcionar online, mas também offline. A internet pode cair, neste caso a aplicação deveria salvar e consultar um banco de dados local, mas quando online, estes dois bancos deveriam ser sincronizados. Lembrando que nesse meio tempo, o banco online também poderia sofrer alguma alteração.

Qual a melhor maneira de fazer algo assim??

A aplicação é um sistema de cadastro de pedidos. É para um mercantil. São cadastrados os pedidos com informações tipo: Valor, data, data de entrega, data de pagamento, fornecedor, forma de pagamento, etc... E ai tem os usuários, autenticação simples do cakephp.

O que acontece é que nem sempre tem internet, então se faz nescessário que o sistema possa funcionar salvando em um banco local e depois sincronizando com o BD online quando houver conexão.

Em um segundo momento posso pensar em fazer um aplicativo para Desktop, que provavelmente irá usar esta lógica de sincronização, bem como um aplicativo Móvel. Mas sempre centralizando e distribuindo a informação através de um único servidor na web.

Comment: É um problema muito interessante, mas você precisa fornecer mais informações sobre a sua aplicação, o que ela faz? ela tem usuários? os usuários interagem com coisas que afetam outros usuários? a solução vai depender muito do contexto e dependendo do seu caso talvez nem seja possível construir algo confiável nessa arquitetura.

Comment: A aplicação é um sistema de cadastro de pedidos. É para um mercantil. São cadastrados os pedidos com informações tipo: Valor, data, data de entrega, data de pagamento, fornecedor, forma de pagamento, etc... E ai tem os usuários, autenticação simples do cakephp.

O que acontece é que nem sempre tem internet, então se faz nescessário que o sistema possa funcionar salvando em um banco local e depois sincronizando com o BD online quando houver conexão.

Comment: E os usuários podem alterar cadastros alheios? por exemplo eu cadastro um pedido e outro user pode editar este pedido?

Comment: sim, basta login de administrador e senha pra entrar e editar, cadastrar ou deletar. Inclusive editar de outros usuários sim.

Comment: Hm, é possível fazer algo assim mas é razoávelmente complicado e você vai ter problemas de conflitos devido a um usuário poder editar pedidos de outros. Vou ver se formulo uma resposta.

Comment: ok, agradeço !!

Comment: O banco centralizado será atualizado por alguém ou apenas pela sincronização dos demais bancos?

Comment: O que for mais fácil.

Comment: Você teve alguma solução para este caso @LucianoBraga, se tiver compartilha conosco, também estou precisando de uma solução para um caso parecido

Comment: A solução que encontrei, inclusive agora para um projeto parecido foi usar o Firebase. Ele permite a sincronização de dados, mantendo um banco de dados offline caso haja quena na conexão. É possível criar algo assim através do IndexedDB, mas o Firestore já oferece tudo isso ponto pra usar.